# Bootstrap CSS and Navbar - How to decrease space between items?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm right now trying to decrease the spacing between items in my navbar which is being styled with both custom CSS and Bootstrap. Right now the spacing is far too late and this seems to be because Bootstrap tries to space navbar items evenly across the entire nav element. I want them to be positioned to the left with less spacing between them.

I have been able to fix positioning them to the right by setting the margin of .container to 0, however there is still far too much space between the navbar items.

By looking at chrome developer tools it looks as if this spacing is coming from the content of the element itself, no from padding or margins. There is no padding or margin on the navbar items.

HTML and CSS code are displayed below as well to linked images of my website and my website with chrome developer tools enabled showing specific spacing information.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #272727;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*
#header-nav .container {
 margin: 0;
}
*/

#header-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        <a href="#about"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> About</a>
        <a href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
        <a href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Vote</a>
        <a href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTrNY.png)

[Chrome DevTools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acD3v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Navbar class should change to `navbar-nav` and margin-left should be auto to set your navbar float left by `ml-auto`. Or Use Flex Box I add to your CSS file which is Commented for the container.
For Spacing between items, you can use `margin-right` in your CSS file.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background-color: dimgray;
}

#header-nav {
 background-color: #272727;
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* you can also use flex box 
#header-nav .container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
*/

#header-nav a {
 color: #FFF;
  margin-right: 2rem; /* Space Between Items */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">
  
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
 

 </head>



 <body>

  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <div class="container">
     <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
     <a href="#about"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> About</a>
     <a href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
     <a href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Vote</a>
     <a href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did the trick, thank you! New to bootstrap, really should read up on their documentation. Also probably doesn't help that I've been following quite an old full stack course.

Comment: Your welcome my friend, definitely read bootstraps documentation and change your course if they are old.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `justify-content-start` class to the `container` class `<div>`.

```
<div class="container justify-content-start"> <!-- Add justify-content-start -->
```

2. Change the margin of the `<a>` tag in CSS.

```
#header-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0.25rem; /* You may change the margin here. 0.25rem is the margin-left and margin-right */
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: #272727;
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*
#header-nav .container {
 margin: 0;
}
*/

#header-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0.25rem; /* You may change the margin here */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



</head>



<body>

  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default ">
      <div class="container justify-content-start"> <!-- Add justify-content-start -->
        <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        <a href="#about"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> About</a>
        <a href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
        <a href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Vote</a>
        <a href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two line in your style.Bootstrap ***navbar*** class use flexbox so you have to adjust ***justify-content*** property manually.(You can adjust padding for anchor tag youself).

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 background-color: dimgray;
}
.navbar .container{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.navbar .container a{
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#header-nav {
 background-color: #272727;
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
#header-nav .container {
 margin: 0;
}
*/

#header-nav a {
 color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">
  
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
 

 </head>



 <body>

  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
     <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
     <a href="#about"><i class="fas fa-question"></i> About</a>
     <a href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
     <a href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-vote-yea"></i> Vote</a>
     <a href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add just two line in style property   .navbar .container{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.navbar .container a{
    padding: 5px 10px;
}